# All finite languages can be decribed using a regular expression?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I have a question.
All finite languages can be decribed using a regular expression?

Comment: What do you think? Have you tried proving this or looking for a counterexample?

Comment: I am looking for a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that a finite language consists of words $w_1, w_2, \dots, w_n$.

Then what do you think the regular expression `^(w1 | w2 | ... | wn)$` matches?

Comment: ohhh i see... But that expression say nothing about the generation of the words on the language... but this is another point.